# Parallel transactions in knex

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Is there any way to get a [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) transaction working in parallel?

- Knex [doesn't support multiple queries in one go](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/257#issuecomment-41682716)
- A stop-gap solution could be to enable connection pooling and execute the queries in parallel, using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

#### However, the parallel solution wouldn't work with transactions

A transaction needs to execute all it's queries on the same connection, thus calls to `Promise.all()` are fast when executed *not as part of a transaction*, and slow when executed as part of a transaction

```
// can be called as part of a transaction, or not
getAllData: function(trx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let data = {};

    Promise.all([
      getFoo(trx), // knex query using `trx` as the knex instance
      getBar(trx)  // knex query using `trx` as the knex instance
    ]).then((result) => {
      data.foo = result[0];
      data.bar = result[1];

      resolve(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    })
  });
}
```

I could use `knex.raw()` and do actual multiple-statements queries in one go but that would couple the DB calls with the DB, thus eliminating knex's added value of being a DB abstraction layer

Comment: This was opened as [Knex issue #1806](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1806) at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Knex Query Builder](http://knexjs.org/#Builder) to build the queries, then join those queries with `;`, and then use `knex.raw()` to execute them in raw mode.

To use Knex without a connection, you can pass an empty object as the initial config, then you can write your queries and then call `.toString()` on them to get the actual raw query.

```
const knex = require('knex')({});
let query = knex('users').insert({id: 10, name: 'Amir'}).toString();
console.log(query);
// insert into "users" ("id", "name") values (10, 'Amir')
```

If you need, you can have an array of knex queries. Calling `.toString()` on all of them and join the resulting array with `;` should give you what you need.

```
const knex = require('knex')({});

let queries = [
    knex('users').insert({id: 10, name: 'Amir'}),
    knex('blogs').insert({user_id: 10, title: 'My New Blog'}),
    knex('configs').insert({user_id: 10, key: 'value'})
];

let query = queries.map(q => q.toString()).join('; ');
console.log(query);
// insert into "users" ("id", "name") values (10, 'Amir'); insert into "blogs" ("title", "user_id") values ('My New Blog', 10); insert into "configs" ("key", "user_id") values ('value', 10)
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you share with us an example?

Comment: Cool. IMO this should be supported by Knex, anyway I think this will works correctly. Upvoted :)

Comment: Yeah it would but **not for transactions**

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution:

```js
// can be called as part of a transaction, or not
getAllData: function(trx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getFoo(trx)  // knex query using `trx` as the knex instance
      .then((foo) => {
        return getBar(trx)  // knex query using `trx` as the knex instance
          .then((bar) => {
            resolve({ foo, bar });
          });
      }, reject);
  });
}
```

It might even be simple:

```js
// can be called as part of a transaction, or not
getAllData: function(trx) {
  return getFoo(trx)  // knex query using `trx` as the knex instance
    .then((foo) => {
      return getBar(trx)  // knex query using `trx` as the knex instance
        .then((bar) => {
          return { foo, bar };
        });
    }, reject);
}
```

Comment: These are not *parallel* transactions. In fact I think the premise of this question is wrong. You can't do parallel transactions on the DB-level.

Comment: That’s true, Knex can’t execute parallel transactions, I just proposed a solution to avoid the error, and that is create a promise with a queue promises.